# Request timeout in ios5

Tags: ios

Creating a very simple iOS 5 application that consumes a .net webservice. It does have two types of NSURLConnection one that is having a timeout of about 20 seconds in its request while another one has a very large timeout [of about 999999999 ]. Both the connections works fine and be able to get response. There is also no limit on the number of connections at server side. While testing this simple application on iOS device, I observed that it works fine but sometimes I get request timeout errors. Googled a lot on this but not able to get a satisfactory answer of why one gets request timeout errors in a properly working web service interface in iOS. The .net web service also do not requires any authentication for the requests. 
Is it entirely not possible to avoid the 'request timeout' issue in iOS application?
Does it results due to excessive calls to web service methods?
Can anybody help in clarifying this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Did you get the answer for this? I am having the same problem! I have an URL that timeout on device but when access it through Safari, it doesn't timeout!! I can't really figure out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

> Googled a lot on this but not able to get a satisfactory answer of why
>   one gets request timeout errors in a properly working web service
>   interface in iOS.

In my experience, your connections give you timeout errors in iOS when they time out. Why do you think this is not the case?

You say one of your connections has a timeout of only 20 seconds. There's a lot that can happen between you and your web service that can take longer than 20 seconds -- especially on the EDGE or 3G radio on the phone. Even a DNS lookup can, in theory, take that long.

At any rate, I've never had an `NSURLConnection` flake out on me and time out for no reason. Double check your network connections and routes. If all seems well, maybe try posting some code?